# How to assign label to gmail programmatically using imap store command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, gmail-imap

I have tried to assign a label to the email.

> a011 STORE 1 +X-GM-LABELS (abc xyz)

It is given in google developer docs(https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions),

But in the above case, it will create 2 separate labels and assign a label in that.

I want to assign a label to email in "abc xyz", is there any way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated, Thankyou.

Comment: How about escaping the `space` symbol with a backspace? `abc\ xyz`. Or encoding the space (`%20` instead of `space`)?

Comment: @emix Yes, I tried this imap_server.store(123, '+X-GM-LABELS', 'abc\ xyz'), but facing error 'Could not parse command'.

Comment: You use double quotes in IMAP for strings.  Look at the example from the documentation:
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante"))

Comment: @Max Not working.

Comment: Great, please show some code so we can help you debug it, rather than the raw commands.

Comment: @Max Please check this

**typ, data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
   imap.store(num, '+X-GM-LABELS', 'abc xyz')**

Here, IMAP is an instance from the IMAP library in python3.

Comment: Did you try IMAP.store(num, '+X-GM-LABELS', '"abc xyz"').  In the future, please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Max, This solution is working.